# grails spring-security with facebook and remember me

Tags: grails, spring-security, remember-me

I have a grails 2.2.3 project which authenticates with spring-security-core (1.2.7.3) and spring-security-facebook (0.14.5). For rememberMe functionality i have the following in my **Config.grooy**:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.alwaysRemember=true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.cookieName="myRememberMeCookieName"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.rememberMe.key="myRememberMeKEY"
```

When logging in with username/password on the "/login/auth" page the *myRememberMeCookieName* Cookie is created and works correctly. But after successfully logging in with Facebook no *myRememberMeCookieName* Cookie is created. I use Server Side Authentication type: [FacebookAuthRedirectFilter](http://splix.github.io/grails-spring-security-facebook/guide/single.html#3.3%20Server%20Side%20Authentication).

How to enable rememberMe functionality when logging in with spring-security-facebook?

Comment: That was a bug. Please upgrade to version 0.15 of the plugin

Comment: Thank you Igor! Works very well with spring-security-facebook:0.15